# Multi injection in dagger

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger

Is it possible to get a list of implementations of an interface/class in dagger?

I am looking at something like [Ninject's Multi-Injection](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Multi-injection).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## UPDATED for Dagger2

*Already [documented](http://google.github.io/dagger/multibindings.html)*.

**TL;DR**:

In your provider

```
@Provides @IntoSet Foo provideAFoo() { return AFoo(); }
```

... other module or same module ...

```
@Provides @IntoSet Foo provideBFoo() { return BFoo(); }
```

... and somewhere else...

```
class Bar { 
    @Inject Set<Foo> allMyFoos; 
}
```

Starting with Dagger2, the dependencies can be mapped (i.e., `java.util.Map`).

## Original Answer *(applicable for Dagger1)*

Looks like the documentation is not complete, but Dagger already provides this.

for example (extracted from dagger's google group), provide the implementations using [Provides.Type.SET](http://square.github.io/dagger/javadoc/dagger/Provides.Type.html#SET)

```
@Provides(type=SET) Foo provideAFoo() { return AFoo(); }
```

... other module or same module ...

```
@Provides(type=SET) Foo provideBFoo() { return BFoo(); }
```

... and somewhere else...

```
class Bar { 
    @Inject Set<Foo> allMyFoos; 
}
```

*REF: [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dagger-discuss/s8_5Xl4TjrY) in dagger's google group*